# JavaCV EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when saving image

Tags: java, opencv, video-processing, image-recognition, javacv

So I'm using JavaCV and trying to capture frames as images from an mp4 file. I keep getting an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when I try to save the images and have not been able to find a solution anywhere. OpenCV, JavaCV, and Java are all the same bitness (64). I also have 64bit visual c++ installed. Here is the code I am using any idea what is causing this or what an alternative solution would be. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
      public class VideoTest {

        public static void main(final String args[]) {
            VideoTest vt = new VideoTest();
            IplImage[] images = vt.extractVideoFrames("video.mp4");
            int i = 1;
            //Save images
            for(IplImage image : images) {
                /* Exception_ACCESS_VIOLATION occurs here */
                cvSaveImage(Integer.toString(i) + ".jpg", image);
                i++;
            }
        }

        /* Extract at least 30 frames from the video at even intervals */
        private IplImage[] extractVideoFrames(String videoName) {
            FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoName);
            try {
                grabber.start();
            } catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            double frameLength = grabber.getLengthInFrames();
            int increment = (int) Math.ceil(frameLength / 30);
            if (frameLength < 30) {
                System.err.println("Not enough frames");
            }

            IplImage[] faceImgArr = new IplImage[30];

            /* Ensure we don't go past end of video and get at least 30 frames */
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < frameLength && j <= 30; i += increment, j++) {
                try {
                    if ((grabber.getFrameNumber() % increment) == 0) {
                        faceImgArr[j] = grabber.grab();
                    } else {
                        grabber.grabFrame();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Error grabbing frame");
                }
            }

            return faceImgArr;
        }

    }

Error Message:
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066de1630, pid=1328, tid=7016
#
# JRE version: 6.0_32-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.7-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [opencv_ffmpeg242_64.dll+0x5a1630]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\name\workspace\Video\hs_err_pid1328.log
#


Snippet from log:
Stack: [0x0000000002900000,0x0000000002a00000],  sp=0x00000000029fec30,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [opencv_ffmpeg242_64.dll+0x5a1630]  cvWriteFrame_FFMPEG+0x59e2b0

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvCreateFileCapture(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_highgui$CvCapture;+0
j  com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.start()V+22
j  main.recognition.VideoTest.extractVideoFrames(Ljava/lang/String;)[Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;+10
j  main.recognition.VideoTest.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally access violation happen in Javacv code because of variables going out of scope (JNI acts a bit different from normal case. Please refer to this post how I solved my access violation http://tech.thecoolblogs.com/2012/10/exceptionaccessviolation-while-using.html)

To solve your issue, first try the entire code in one single scope.. I mean in one method and within one try.. catch block. If that works, we can assume that this issue is clearly related to some variable going out of scope. Then try moving around the IplImage creating and see if it go away.

If it still does nt work (after merging on to same method and scope), please check the temp folder (C:\users\ur id\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp** folder to see if the dll files are copied over

Comment: That link is terrible.